# Pass or Emit an event from child component to the parent component in Vue Js with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to pass an event to the parent component from the child component. I'm new to this and stuck at it. Basically, it is a dashboard having just a side panel and displaying area. The displaying area is in the dashboard template itself without a separate component.

This is my code for the dashboard.vue

```
<template>
    <app-layout title="Dashboard">
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Dashboard
            </h2>
        </template>

        <div class="h-screen bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl grid grid-cols-5">
            <click/>
            <div>
                {{msg}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue'
    import click from '@/Components/click.vue'
    
    export default {
        components: {
            AppLayout,
            click,
        },
        data(){
            return{
                msg:'1'
            }
        },methods:{
            addValue:function(){
                this.msg++
            }
        }
   }
</script>
```

And This is my click.vue component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button v-on:click="add" class="border-solid font-semibold hover:bg-blue-600 hover:text-white border-b-2 w-full py-5" id="click">Click ME 1</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    methods:{
            add:function(){
                this.$parent.$emit('addValue');
            }
        
        }}
</script>
```

I'm trying to trigger the addValue() in Dashboard.vue from Click.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use inject/provide pattern :

in root component :

```
methods:{
            addValue:function(){
                this.msg++
            }
 },
provide: function () {
  return {
    addValue: this.addValue
  }
}
```

in grandchild component inject the method and run it from your method:

```
    export default {
    inject: ['addValue'],
    methods:{
            add:function(){
                this.addValue();
            }
        
        }}
```